# Prevent installation of a phase listener from included jar in jsf 2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF 2 application that includes a jar file which in turn contains a faces-config.xml in its META-INF directory. The faces-config.xml contains a declaration of a phase-listener. I would like to prevent the installation of this phase listener without modifying the jar file itself.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't block specific parts of `faces-config.xml` in a 3rd party JAR from being interpreted.

You have basically 2 options:

1. Block the whole `faces-config.xml` in a 3rd party JAR from being interpreted by adding `metadata-complete="true"` to webapp's own `faces-config.xml`.

   ```
   <faces-config ... metadata-complete="true">
   ```

   Note that this also skips annotation scans in classes of the 3rd party JAR. You'd basically need to redefine specific parts you'd like to use in webapp's own `faces-config.xml`.

   ---
2. Provide a custom [`Lifecycle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html) implementation via [`LifecycleFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/lifecycle/LifecycleFactory.html) which you register in `<factory><lifecycle-factory>` of webapp's `faces-config.xml`. In that implementation, override [`addPhaseListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html#addPhaseListener%28javax.faces.event.PhaseListener%29) accordingly to perform e.g. an `instanceof` check before skipping or continuing.

Comment: option 2 is probably the simplest thing for me considering there are multiple other 3rd party library's I want to behave properly.

Comment: A third option, beyond your control, would be to post a feature request to the library vendor that the phase listener should skip its job when e.g. a certain context parameter, or request parameter,  or session attribute, or even an environment variable is present, depending on the phase listener's actual job/responsibility.